# Placing a numpy record array inside another record array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following record array. But each element needs it's own record array describing information about that element. Right now this isn't code I am just displaying the information in a readable way. For example:

I have a collection of registers with attributes like width and offset.

List of registers

```
Registers     offsets    width

Register_1    1          5
Register_2    2          10
Register_3    3          15
Register_4    4          20
```

Each register also has a set of fields which have specific values like bit and length

Inside of register_1 we have the following fields

```
register_1
{
#field names      bit     length
field_1           1       10
field_2           2       20
field_3           3       30
```

}

Actual python code

```
dtype={
    'names' : ('name','offset','width'),
    'formats' : ('U20','U20','U20')}

registers= np.zeros(10,dtype)

registers[0]=('register_1','1','5')
registers[1]=('register_2','2','10')
registers[2]=('register_3','3','15')
registers[3]=('register_4','4','20')
```

Now I want to associate each register with their fields, the first thing that came to mind was nesting another record array in my register record array.

Pseudo python code

```
type={
    'names' : ('name','bit','length'),
    'formats' : ('U20','U20','U20')}

fields= np.zeros(10,type)

 dtype={
    'names' : ('name','offset','width',fields),
    'formats' : ('U20','U20','U20','U20')}

regsiters= np.zeros(10,dtype)
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Does every register have the same number of fields?

Comment: No the number of field's vary per register, but I wouldn't think that would be an issue.

Comment: What sort of indexing operations are you most likely to want to perform. For example, are you mostly going to be indexing by register or by field?

Comment: Well I will be printing out the data, sometimes by register name, others by the register name and all of its fields.

Comment: Given that it sounds like you're indexing your data exclusively by register, it seems to me that you're probably better off storing your "field" data in something more like a set of nested dicts. Numpy arrays are really designed for flat rather than nested data structures. Technically you could nest a recarray inside another by abusing the `np.object` dtype, but at that point you might as well use a plain Python list, since you lose the performance benefits of numpy arrays by using them to store arbitrary Python objects.

Comment: Can you please go into more depth about nesting a recarray in another by using the np.object method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your `type` (bad name!) into a `dtype`:

```
In [277]: dt1=np.dtype(type)
In [278]: dt1
Out[278]: dtype([('name', '<U20'), ('bit', '<U20'), ('length', '<U20')])
```

build a composite `dtype`.  Notice that the format for 'fields' is `(dt1,3)` - i.e. a subarray consisting of 3 elements of type `dt1`.

```
In [279]: dt2=np.dtype({
    'names' : ('name','offset','width','fields'),
    'formats' : ('U20','U20','U20',(dt1,3))})
In [280]: registers=np.zeros(4,dtype=dt2)
In [281]: registers
Out[281]: 
array([('', '', '', [('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')]),
       ('', '', '', [('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')]),
       ('', '', '', [('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')]),
       ('', '', '', [('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')])], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U20'), ('offset', '<U20'), ('width', '<U20'), ('fields', [('name', '<U20'), ('bit', '<U20'), ('length', '<U20')], (3,))])
```

Fill in the names:

```
In [283]: registers['name']='register_1 register_2 register_3 register_4'.split()
```

and other 2 fields:

```
In [284]: registers['offset']=[1,2,3,4]
In [285]: registers['width']=[5,10,15,20]
In [286]: registers
Out[286]: 
array([('register_1', '1', '5', [('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')]),
       ('register_2', '2', '10', [('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')]),
       ('register_3', '3', '15', [('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')]),
       ('register_4', '4', '20', [('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')])], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U20'), ('offset', '<U20'), ('width', '<U20'), ('fields', [('name', '<U20'), ('bit', '<U20'), ('length', '<U20')], (3,))])
```

The `fields` value for `registers[0]` element can be filled in in the same way:

```
In [288]: registers[0]['fields']
Out[288]: 
array([('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U20'), ('bit', '<U20'), ('length', '<U20')])
```

Now that `registers` has 4 fields, you can't fill in 3 of them with:

```
In [289]: registers[0]=('register_1','1','5')
...
ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.
```

The tuple has include all the values needed for the 'fields' field (why did you choose confusing names like this?).

Create an array with `dtype` `dt1`, and fill it.

```
In [290]: regfield=np.zeros(3,dtype=dt1)
In [291]: regfield
Out[291]: 
array([('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U20'), ('bit', '<U20'), ('length', '<U20')])
In [292]: regfield[0]=('field1',1,10)
In [293]: regfield[1]=('field2',2,20)
In [294]: regfield[2]=('field3',3,30)
```

Now you can include it as a value in the `registers` tuple.

```
In [295]: registers[0]=('register_1','1','5',regfield)
In [296]: registers[0]
Out[296]: ('register_1', '1', '5', [('field1', '1', '10'), ('field2', '2', '20'), ('field3', '3', '30')])
```

I can replicate the fieldnames to the other registers with:

```
In [300]: fieldnames=registers['fields']['name'][0]
In [301]: registers['fields']['name']
Out[301]: 
array([['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], 
      dtype='<U20')
In [302]: registers['fields']['name']=fieldnames
In [303]: registers['fields']['name']
Out[303]: 
array([['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],
       ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],
       ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],
       ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']], 
      dtype='<U20')
In [304]: registers['fields']
Out[304]: 
array([[('field1', '1', '10'), ('field2', '2', '20'), ('field3', '3', '30')],
       [('field1', '', ''), ('field2', '', ''), ('field3', '', '')],
       [('field1', '', ''), ('field2', '', ''), ('field3', '', '')],
       [('field1', '', ''), ('field2', '', ''), ('field3', '', '')]], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U20'), ('bit', '<U20'), ('length', '<U20')])
```

---

New dtype:

```
In [333]: dt3=np.dtype({
    'names' : ('name','offset','width','fields'),
    'formats' : ('U20','U20','U20', 'O')})
In [334]: registers=np.zeros(4,dtype=dt3)
In [335]: registers
Out[335]: 
array([('', '', '', 0), ('', '', '', 0), ('', '', '', 0), ('', '', '', 0)], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U20'), ('offset', '<U20'), ('width', '<U20'), ('fields', 'O')])
```

Assign value to `registers[0]`.  `regfield` the 3 element array that I defined earlier.

```
In [337]: registers[0]=('register_1', '1', '5', regfield)
In [338]: registers
Out[338]: 
array([ ('register_1', '1', '5', [('field1', '1', '10'), ('field2', '2', '20'), ('field3', '3', '30')]),
       ('', '', '', 0), 
       ('', '', '', 0), 
       ('', '', '', 0)], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U20'), ('offset', '<U20'), ('width', '<U20'), ('fields', 'O')])
...
```

Display is similar to what what we had before, but now each register can have a different number of `fields`.

We can verify that object in the `fields' field of`registers[0]`is the`regfield` array by looking at their ids.

```
In [343]: id(regfield)
Out[343]: 166843840
In [344]: id(registers[0]['fields'])
Out[344]: 166843840
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so you are placing each of these in a specific point in the array?  Can you explain the  In[300]? And why start at 277?

Comment: The line numbers come from the Ipython session that I've been using for several days.  Sorry, I didn't start a fresh session for your problem. :) At `IN[300] I am experimenting with setting the fields of all of the registers with values that I'd set earlier for `registers[0]`.  No guarantee that it's the best way.

Comment: With `dt2` the fields data is placed inline with the other `registers` fields.  And all `registers` must have the same number of `fields`.  Alternative this field could be `dtype=object` as @ali_m suggests.  Then only a pointer is placed in the `registers` array, and the `fields` data is located in separate arrays elsewhere in memory.

Comment: Hi, just mess around with the code, this is exactly what I wanted thank you!

Comment: I added the `dtype=object` variant.